# Optimize a query multiple tables & Multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, codeigniter

I need to optimize the query which has multiple joins. And also with multiple OR AND conditions which varies depending upon the user input.

The query which gets generated is:

```
SELECT  emp.name as entryby, l.cname as location_name, sp.product AS product_name, 
        sp.refcode as pro_refcode, sup.vendorname, sp.mrpgross AS mrpgross,
        pro.cp AS cost_price, cust.name AS customer_names, cust.phone AS mobile_no,
        sp.uom1 as TotalQTY, sp.category_name, auth.*
FROM erp_salesorderproductsdetails sp
LEFT JOIN erp_salesorder s ON s.id = sp.salesorder_id
LEFT JOIN geopos_employees emp ON emp.id = s.entryby
LEFT JOIN geopos_locations l ON s.loc = l.id
LEFT JOIN geopos_productall pro ON pro.product_code = sp.refcode
LEFT JOIN geopos_supplier sup ON sup.id = pro.vendor
LEFT JOIN geopos_customers cust ON cust.id = s.customer
LEFT JOIN authorize_po auth ON auth.salesorder_id = s.id
WHERE sp.salesorder_id = 301 
AND ( sp.category_name IN(SPECTACLES, SPECTACLE LENSES) )
OR sp.salesorder_id = 310 
AND ( sp.category_name IN(SPECTACLES, SPECTACLE LENSES) )
OR sp.salesorder_id = 3234 
AND (sp.category_name IN(SPECTACLES, SPECTACLE LENSES) )
```

Here, the `sp.salesorder_id` along with AND in where condition can be multiple depending upon the users input.
To retrieve some 700 - 800 records it takes around 2 to 3.5 mins.

But mostly the data counts goes to over 2000. In that case its not performing very efficiently. Can anybody suggest anything ?

I have also shared the Explain result of the query being generated. However, sharing the Table structure won't be a good idea as some tables have columns  more than 50.

```
1   SIMPLE  sp  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6211    Using where 
1   SIMPLE  s   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   erp_billing.sp.salesorder_id    1       
1   SIMPLE  emp eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   erp_billing.s.entryby   1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  l   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   erp_billing.s.loc   1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  pro ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    340264  Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) 
1   SIMPLE  sup eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   erp_billing.pro.vendor  1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  cust    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   erp_billing.s.customer  1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  auth    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13  Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
```

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thank you for your suggestion, I have updated my question shared the result my query within. However, I think sharing the table structure would get very confusing as some tables have more than 50 columns. I have also tried the Where IN condition but I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: Looks like there is no index on geopos_productall.product_code and on erp_salesorderproductsdetails.salesorder_id.  What's the indexes on these tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding the following  composite keys:

```
ALTER TABLE erp_salesorderproductsdetails ADD INDEX `idx_1` (`salesorder_id`,`category_name`);
ALTER TABLE geopos_productall ADD INDEX `idx_2` (`product_code`,`vendor`);
ALTER TABLE erp_salesorder  ADD INDEX `idx_3` (`id`,`entryby`,`customer`);
```

Change the last query part from

```
WHERE sp.salesorder_id = 301 
AND ( sp.category_name IN(SPECTACLES, SPECTACLE LENSES) )
OR sp.salesorder_id = 310 
AND ( sp.category_name IN(SPECTACLES, SPECTACLE LENSES) )
OR sp.salesorder_id = 3234 
AND (sp.category_name IN(SPECTACLES, SPECTACLE LENSES) )
```

to

```
WHERE sp.salesorder_id in (301,310,3234) 
AND  sp.category_name IN('SPECTACLES', 'SPECTACLE LENSES')
```

EDIT: Add another key on authorize_po table

```
ALTER TABLE authorize_po  ADD INDEX `salesorder_id` (`salesorder_id`);
```

Comment: I have made the above suggested changes in my database. How help with something on how am I supposed to use those Indexes in my query ?

Comment: The query execution time has been decreased to 1.5 seconds for the same no. of records mentioned in the question. And I have shared a link to the result of EXPLAIN https://prnt.sc/fqaStP9u7I1x

Comment: Yeah, that works like a charm & seems to have resolved my major concern. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: And `auth` needs `INDEX(salesorder_id)`